# How to get count on v-if list with variable?

Tags: vuejs2

I want to show one list based one variable, but if I show {{ i }} represents entire count, how I get count only the current list?

Thats my code:

```
<tr v-for="(item, i) in placares" v-if="item.dificuldade == dificuldadeAtual.nome">
    <td>{{ i }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.nome }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.fase }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.pontos | formatNumber }}</td>
</tr>
```

The app is running here: http://digitacao.serraonline.net.br/

Comment: One option is to create a computed variable that returns `placares.filter(function(item) { return item.dificuldade == dificuldadeAtual.nome } )` and then change your v-for to use that filtered array.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so clear but i think this will help you:

```
<tr v-for="(item, index) in placares">
   <div v-if="item.dificuldade == dificuldadeAtual.nome">
    <td>{{ index }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.nome }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.fase }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.pontos | formatNumber }}</td>
   </div>
</tr>
```

Don't use v-for and v-if in same element, v-for will get priority.

Answer (score 0):

It's not semantic, i solved the problem using one method to filter the list

```
methods:{    
    filterPlacar(dificuldade){
        return _.take(_.filter(this.placares, item => {
        return item.dificuldade.indexOf(dificuldade) >=0;
        }),15);
    }
}
```

And the v-for:

```
<tr v-for="(item, j) in filterPlacar(dificuldadeAtual.nome)">
    <td>{{ ++j }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.nome }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.fase }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.pontos | formatNumber }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Rather than using a method you should consider a computed

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please mark it correct. Please don't put "[SOLVED]" in the title.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `v-if` with `v-show` like:

```
<tr v-for="(item, i) in placares" v-show="item.dificuldade == dificuldadeAtual.nome">
  <td>{{ i }}</td>
  <td>{{ item.nome }}</td>
  <td>{{ item.fase }}</td>
  <td>{{ item.pontos | formatNumber }}</td>
</tr>
```

or use `v-if` in your `td`s like:

```
<tr v-for="(item, i) in placares">
  <template v-if="item.dificuldade == dificuldadeAtual.nome">
    <td>{{ i }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.nome }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.fase }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.pontos | formatNumber }}</td>
  </template>
</tr>
```